# Strange Behavior When Populating EditText field

Tags: android

I am passing a String from one activity to another, and placing it into an EditText box.

My problem is, I am placing the string "S" into the EditText box, but the cursor is BEHIND the character, instead of in FRONT of it, so the user has to hit the arrow to move the cursor so they can continue typing.

Is there a setting I need to adjust so the cursor stays in FRONT of the letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the edit text.

```
edittext.setSelection(str.length());
```

Comment: Thank you! It was bugging me for quite a while now! :-)

Answer (score 0):

To set the cursor you can call:

```
editText.setSelection(positionOfCursor);
```